# Draw an image without GLKView in OpenGL ES iOS

Tags: ios9, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard, glkit

Working with OpenGL ES 2.0 (first time to work with graphics libraries). I am getting an image from server and the same I am trying to display the same to a custom view (In my case its Google cardboard view - GCSCardboardView which expects 3D rendering using OpenGL).

For rendering any image GLKit provides a way using GLKView. Is there any way I can directly draw this to GCSCardboardView (so that I can enable virtual reality) ?

Comment: This depends on what you want. In general you might be able to simply add an image view as a subview to the cardboards view and show it if this is your goal. Otherwise you may draw it somewhere in the cardboard view draw pipeline which means searching for "how to draw a texture".

Comment: Ok my goal is to add google streetview into cardboard view. i.e., have to display the streetview images in cardboard view. When i add an image to cardboard view, i am not able to see its 360º view from cardboard device. It only shows like a normal image. GCSCardboardView is a cardboard class where it provides delegate methods for 3D rendering using OpenGL ES. Drawing a texture requires a GLKView but i need to render on cardboard view. I am doing cardboard/GL stuff first time so correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: The issue is still in what is your expected result. How should these images look like. Are they supposed to be inside the scene as billboards which rotate with the scene itself...